# Rectifying awk statement

Tags: awk

I have a file as below to do date and number validation. **File**:

```
006063416.01|USD|1| |00.00000|00.00000|O| |20100802|20160119| |D|+0000006063416|0000000000|          |060.634164000|   
06063416.001|AUD|M| |00.00000|00.00000|O| |2015991130|20160319| |D|+0000006063416|0000000000|          |006a063416096|  
06063416.002|HKD|M| |00.00000|00.00000|O| |20151130|20168919| |D|+0000006063416|0000000000|          |006063416075|
```

**Script**:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
validate() {
echo "Performing file  validations ..."
file=/var/applications/scripts/bin/CLIMAMT_SG
CURR_DTTM=`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`
output=/var/applications/scripts/bin/output_CLIMAMT_SG.${CURR_DTTM}
awk -F\| '$16 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print "Line:"NR" Field:16 "$16" is not Numeric"}(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$10")+0 != "$10"{print "Line:"NR" Field:10 "$10" is not in date format";next}' $file > $output
echo "Validation Complete"}  
validate
```

**output**:

```
Line:1 Field:16 060.634164000 is not Numeric  
Line:1 Field:10 20160119 is not in date format  
Line:2 Field:16 006a063416096 is not Numeric  
Line:2 Field:10 20160319 is not in date format  
Line:3 Field:10 20168919 is not in date format
```

**problem** is that even 20160319 is reported as incorrect

Comment: I think you may want to fix the formatting of your question a bit. It's hard to make out what's what.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not actually passing the `date` command to the system. Also `+0` doesn't seem to make any sense (it's a *string*, surely?).

Comment: @Kusalananda - rectified formatting

Comment: @steeldriver - I am not sure how to add the date check condition, so did this.pls suggest

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$10")+0 != "$10"{print "Line:"NR" Field:10 "$10" is not in date format";next}
```

does **not** call out the the external `date` command. awk parses that like this:

1. the `-` operator has higher precedence than string concatenation, so first we take the string "%Y%m%d" and subtract the variable `d`, resulting in the value `0`
2. now we take the value of the `date` variable (which is empty) and concatenate 0 and the string "$10" (*not* the value of the 10th field)
3. this results in the string `"0$10"`
4. then we add zero to that string, resulting in the value zero
5. and compare that to the value of the 10th field.

That will only match if you have `0` in the 10th field.

GNU awk has some time functions, so you could do something like (untested)

```
function validate_date(datestr,   timespec) {
    timespec = substr(datestr,1,4) " " substr(datestr,5,2) " " substr(datestr,7,2) " 0 0 0")
    return mktime(timespec)
}

{
    if (validate_date($10) == -1) {
        print $10 " is an invalid date"
    }
}
```

Comment: gawk `mktime`, like the standard C library routine, accepts out-of-range fields and 'normalizes' them, e.g. `mktime("2017 01 32 30 70 00")` gives the `time_t` value for 2017/02/02 07:10:00, not -1. That's why I `strftime` back and check it matches the input.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$10")+0` in awk when variables `date` and `d` are unset subtracts the two strings `+%Y%m%d` which has a numeric value of zero and (the value of) field 10 which in this case might be `20161499` thus producing the value -20161499.</strike> I got this part wrong and glenn got it right, but either way it *doesn't* run `date` as desired.

To run a command from awk and get its output, use the pipe form of `getline` [(see info on your system or online)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe) but you can't fit it entirely in a condition so make it part of your action:

```
{ cmd = "date +%Y%m%d -d " $10; cmd | getline checktime; close (cmd);
  if( checktime != $10 ) { print "invalid time" $10; next } }
```

Alternatively if you have GNU `awk` (and if you have GNU `date` you probably do) you can use the [builtin functions `mktime` and `strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)
(which do fit in a moderately complicated condition)

```
 strftime("%Y%m%d", mktime(substr($10,1,4)" "substr($10,5,2)" "substr($10,7,2)" 00 00 00")) == $10
```

Comment: heh, we have slightly different interpretations of how that code snippet gets evaluated.

Comment: @glennjackman: you're right on the expression, but sadly not quite on the mktime